# Kali Linux not starting

Tags: linux, kali-linux, login-screen, 32-vs-64-bit

I am beginner in Linux Systems. I had downloaded Kali 3 32-Bit to run on a 64 Bit computer. However it is only working with 32-Bit Computers. I don't know why but the login screen doesn't comes in 64 Bit Computer, Lenovo ideapad 300.

Please help if anyone can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preamble** (vaguely related to the main issue)

*beginner in Linux* and *Kali* is a mismatch. The Kali distro isn't intended as a daily driver. A "beginner in Linux" should be using distros designed for Desktop Linux, typically Ubuntu and derivatives or many others, but not Kali: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

**The main issue**

The Lenovo Ideapad 3000 is a current model, 64-bit hardware and UEFI.

Old BIOS 64-bit PCs could easily run a 64-bit or 32-bit OS. Contemporary machines with UEFI instead of BIOS, in practical rather than strictly technical terms, really require a 64-bit OS and there's absolutely no reason not to use a 64-bit OS.

Kali 32-bit (or any other 32-bit Linux distro) can be used in a Virtual Machine in a 64-bit host OS. For the intended purpose of Kali running in a VM, the architecture won't make a difference.

**Suggestion**: Install the OS you're familiar with or use the virtualization software of your choice. Oracle Virtualbox is arguably the easiest for beginners and is available for Linux, Solaris, OSX and Windows. Create a [Kali VM](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest).

If you want to install Kali in the Lenovo Ideapad 3000 you need [Kali 64-bit or Kali 64-bit Light.](https://www.kali.org/downloads/3/) and boot and install in UEFI mode. Additional hardware configurations may be required.

Comment: I can't emphasize the preamble enough. **Kali is not for beginners**. It's not even for most experts, because it's aimed at a very specific audience (professional penetration testers). Use some other distro.

Comment: Let me say that I am not tooooo Beginner in Linux.

Comment: Is there not anyway that I can use Kali 32 Bit on same computer?

Comment: Why would you want to? And no, there isn't mostly due to UEFI (32-bit Linux distros typically do not support UEFI).

Comment: Actually, this problem was not before. I installed i32 bit on USB and it was working fine. Some days later, I replaced it with encrypted install and from then it only boots, but, the login screen doesn't comes. I want to know why by adding encryption it is not working.

Comment: That's another, different and unrelated, question. I suggest you post a new one with as many details as you can gather, including hardware specifications.